# How to get Python function to update original df

Tags: python, pandas

Can someone please help me understand how to change the original df in my example? (link below). The function makes the changes that I want it to make however, I want it to update the original df that I input into the function. As seen in the code when I call df after the function it returns the original df and not the adjusted one from the function...

Any help greatly appreciated!

[How to get function to change original df?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQHIx.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and include relevant code in the question itself, [as text and not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Anyway, the problem is that writing `df = pd.merge(...` **does not change** the object that was named `df` at the beginning of the function (by being passed as a parameter). It creates a **new** object (via `pd.merge`), then causes `df` to *stop* naming the old object and *start* naming the new one. This *has nothing to do with Pandas* - that's *how `=` works* in Python.

Comment: You can work around this either by getting the Pandas functionality to work in-place (this starts with reading the documentation, and may or may not be possible in general), or by accepting that it works this way and re-assigning the result after the function call. See also https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html to make sure you understand how it works.

Comment: It is also a good idea to [try to look for solutions first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), for example by using a search engine. I found a duplicate by searching for `dataframe merge "in place"` and linked it here. It has some other reference links in the question. I hope it will be sufficient.